# Youtube player shortcut or extension to change to next higher or lower video resolution

Tags: youtube, keyboard-shortcuts, javascript, google-chrome-extensions

I watch general videos on youtube at 720p and programming/ tutorial videos at 1080p
I have searched a lot and its almost certain there is no keyboard shortcut to jump to the next higher/ lower video resolution as per the need.

How can a quick shortcut implemented/ achieved using some extension or a script?

Answer (score 2):

There might be a workaround for this. I've been using **["Hot Keyboard"](https://www.hot-keyboard.com/download/)** macro for the past couple of years to deal with such problems.
It has a very neat keyboard recorder/editor and you can also set several conditions for running a macro with a keyboard shortcut. In this case you can set a keyboard sequence like this to get it done:

```
f(full screen),7tabs(get to setting),space(open setting menue)2down(get to quality),xdown(get to the quality you want),enter/space
```

Then you can assign a keyboard shortcut in 'Hot keyboard' to this sequence. Such solution works seamlessly for me most of the time as if I've added a costume keyboard shortcut to YouTube for myself.

*BTW: The developer of 'Hot Keyboard' seems like a very nice guy. Don't forget to support him with a purchase.*

Comment: hey @dashakol Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately i'm on mac and the Hot Keyboard is only for windows

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[Improve YouTube!](https://improvedtube.com/)** ([Chrome version](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/improve-youtube-video-you/bnomihfieiccainjcjblhegjgglakjdd/) / [Firefox version](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/youtube-addon/)) — an open-source browser extension that can tweak YouTube in various ways, such as setting shortcut keys / hotkeys for various YouTube functionality, like setting the preferred video resolution.

After installing Improve YouTube!, you can set a shortcut key for a preferred resolution by clicking the extension's button → Shortcuts → Quality → choose a resolution → press the key you want to use as a shortcut key to switch to that resolution → click on "Save".

Screenshot of Improve YouTube's settings, where <kbd>A</kbd> is set as the shortcut key for the 720p resolution and <kbd>D</kbd> for the 1080p resolution:

[image: screenshot of settings described above]

<sup>[Declaration of non-affiliation](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4957/7584): I have **NO AFFILIATION** with the "Improve YouTube!" browser extension in any way whatsoever. I'm just a regular user who wanted to share a solution to the OP's question. I found this extension to be a relevant and helpful solution, since it allows me to set shortcut keys for various YouTube functionality, such as the one OP described.</sup>